# regular expression Python search

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract some info from the source code in a webpage and I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about it.
Part of the source code is as follows:

```
<th>Model #:</th>
                                        <td>1561496564</td>
                            </tr>
                                                                                                                                                                   <tr>
```

I want to start at "Model #:" and go all the way up the to td>. From there, I can erase anything that's not a number to get the 1561496564.

I can't do:

```
modelMatch = re.search('Model[^\n]*', contents)
```

because the actual number is on the next line. I also can't do anything that's not a /, d, or >. I'm thinking I can do [^\^n^:^<^/^t^h^>^r]*, but that seems a little messy. I'm wondering if there's a better way.

For regular expression, is there an easy way to say, extract until you reach this specific phrase of "tr"?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't use regex for HTML. Do *not* use regex for HTML. Use Beautiful Soup 4.

Comment: You will be much safer using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) HTML parser.

Comment: Dont use regexp for html/xml parsing. You will never win.
Try python standard modules `html` or `xml`. Also external libraries  like `lxml` or `beautifulsoup` exists.

Comment: Got it. I'll look into beautifulsoup then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable re's multiline mode by pass `re.MULTILINE` parameter.

However, for tasks like extract data from a webpage, I would recommend using tools like [lxml](http://lxml.de/), [pyquery](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/), [Beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead. These approaches would be much simpler and elegant.

Here's an example using pyquery module:

```
In [1]: import pyquery

In [2]: s = '''<th>Model #:</th>
   ...:                                         <td>1561496564</td>
   ...:                             </tr>'''

In [3]: pyquery.PyQuery(s).find('td').text()
Out[3]: '1561496564'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
content = """<th>Model #:</th>
                                    <td>1561496564</td>
                        </tr>
                                                                                                                                                               <tr>"""

re.search(r".*>(\w+\ #\:)<.*>(\d+)<", content.replace('\n', '')).groups()
```

**Output:**

```
('Model #:', '1561496564')
```